# Unsupported operand types: int * Illuminate\Support\Collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have this issue that I can't solve, I don't know how to do the calculation whereas the collections is returning an integer.

```
'data' => $firstCalc->map(function($item) use ($secondCalc) {
    return ($item->pluck('rate')->first() * $secondCalc->map(function($secondItem){
                return $secondItem->pluck('rate')->first() /100;
            }));
}),
```

it returns that error:

> Unsupported operand types: int * Illuminate\Support\Collection
> The error is on this line:

```
return ($item->pluck('rate')->first() * $secondCalc->map(function($secondItem){
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `->map()` returns a new collection (an object) so it makes no sense to use it for multiplication.

Comment: It would help to see what `$firstCalc` and `$secondCalc` actually are

Comment: @M.ErikssonBut but the map returns an integer?!!

Comment: @MatthewBradley these variables are very complex, But they return a collection. It was working before without issue but then I added the second map. Then got that error.

Comment: You insist the `map()` returns an integer. Does it? Did you check? PHP, and the documentation, say it returns [a collection object](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_map).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware When I do `pp($secondItem->pluck('rate')->first());`  it returns an Integer something like "1510".

Comment: And what does it return when you do `dd($secondCalc->map(function($secondItem){ return $secondItem->pluck('rate')->first() /100; }));`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It's a collection of arrays
`Illuminate\Support\Collection {
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "2022-12" => 1528
    "2022-11" => 1495
    "2022-10" => 1456
    "2022-09" => 1476
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}`
So, How can I sync it with the other map?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what this function is supposed to do. But do you understand the error message now? A collection of arrays isn't something you can multiply.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Right, Thank yoyu My focus was on the return of the inside of the map.